# R - Remove records with question marks (or other characters)

Tags: r, character, subset

I have a vector of over a million records, and some records have characters such as ?, *, & in them (the rest of the record entry is alphanumeric).

I need to identify these records (according to the specific character--e.g., the question mark), and delete them from my main data frame as well as subset them into a separate data frame for examination.

I have used grep and pmatch, but have not had success.  Examples of my code for grep and pmatch are:

```
new.df <- df[-grep("\\?",df$vector),]
new.df <- pmatch("?", df$vector)
```

Thanks.

Comment: maybe use `df[!grepl("\\?",df$vector),]` or  `df[-which(grepl("\\?",df$vector)),]` instead. a reproducible example would help as would explaining what you mean by no success

Comment: does `grepl("[*?&]",...)` work

Comment: Thanks rawr!  This worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
df <- data.frame(a=1:10, b=c("a","b?b","c", "d", "e", "f?", "?g", "h", "i", "j"))
matches <- grepl("\\?", df$b) # creates a logical vector for each row: TRUE = match, FALSE = no match
df.hits <- df[matches,]
df.removed <- df[!matches,] # deleting rows is not efficient -> copy the remaining rows into a new data.frame instead
```

You should use a data.table to improve the performance a little bit...